# display image by using selected field as the source path/directory using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How can I display image files depending on 3 select fields (province, year, month). Place and year are folders and the month are the image files. after submit, the image should be displayed on the box below the selection boxes.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

[here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hupqb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) {

    $place = $_POST['province'] . '/';
    $year = $_POST['year'] . '/';
    $month = $_POST['month'] . '.jpg'; // or whatever your format is

    echo '<img src="' . $place . $year . $month . '">';

}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i edited my question and attached photo.

Comment: sorry i said thank you in advance. but it didn't work. thanks for the reply tho. nothing is displayed after submitting

Comment: Can you open your developer tools to check the image? Or you can echo the contents of $_POST to check if the values are correct.

Comment: there's no content when i echo $_POST

Comment: Make sure you use the `name="..."` of your `<select>`